# E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting ,table accounts has no column named control_type (code 1):

Tags: android-sqlite

tHis is my code for create a db table

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + KEY_CTRL_TYPE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_USER_NAME + " TEXT,"+ KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT "
            + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}
```

and this is for add a contact

```
void addContact(Accounts accounts) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, accounts.getName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, accounts.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone
    values.put(KEY_CTRL_TYPE, accounts.getControlType()); //
    values.put(KEY_USER_NAME, accounts.getUserName()); //
    values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, accounts.getPassword()); //


    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

I am getting this error on accessing `addContact`

`db.addContact(new Accounts(siteName,siteNum,ctype,username,pass));`

`29206-29206/com.atrolabe.tcpremote1 E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting control_type=SHAULA 720 user_name=wetyu phone_number=123455566 password=fhhchhjh name=test
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table accounts has no column named control_type (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO accounts(control_type,user_name,phone_number,password,name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)`

the logcat points to this Line in addcontact

`db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually with the initial `onCreate()` method. The resulting SQL is constructed improperly and never creates the `control_type` column. See below:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + KEY_CTRL_TYPE +    ...
```

After the phone number field the `TEXT` keyword is positioned next to the intended `control_type` column name; resulting in unexpected SQL. For example (filling in with expected values)

```
CREATE TABLE Contacts (
            ContactID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  ContactName TEXT,
            ContactNumber TEXTcontrol_type  ...
```

To fix this problem, simply re-format your `CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE` string properly.

Comment: @dmsherazi No, it is improperly concatenated with the SQL keyword preceding it `" TEXT" + KEY_CTRL_TYPE +" TEXT, "` resulting in something like this: `TEXTcontrol_type TEXT,`

Comment: ahh i am mising that `,` after `TEXT` before  `KEY_CTRL_TYPE`